# Chained Unity registration methods

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I recently started a new position and inherited a bit of code that I'm trying to figure out how it's even working in order to refactor the application. I've used Unity before, but dont have a great understanding of everything that it does and how it does it. I've watched a good number of tutorials and none of them touch on code that looks like this. Can anyone explain what the following is doing?

```
unityContainer.RegisterInstance(
                    "IntegrationEntityContent", 
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IntegrationEntities"].ConnectionString,
                    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())                
              .RegisterType<IIntegrationEntities, IntegrationEntities>(
                    new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
                    new InjectionConstructor());
```

I know that RegisterInstance hands out a singleton instance of the object, but it seems like that is only handing out one instance of the connection string. What I can't figure out is how the IntegrationEntities type is getting the connection string from the above code and if the application is getting a new IntegrationEntities instance every time it asks for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unityContainer.RegisterInstance(
                    "IntegrationEntityContent", 
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IntegrationEntities"].ConnectionString,
                    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```

This code does a named registration of the connection string with [ContainerControlledLifetimeManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872(v=pandp.20).aspx), which registers an existing object as a singleton instance.

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<IIntegrationEntities, IntegrationEntities>(
                    new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
                    new InjectionConstructor());
```

The next statement registers the **IntegrationEntities** class with hierarchical lifetime manager. It is similar to singleton lifetime manager, but will return different instances for child containers (if any).

> how the IntegrationEntities type is getting the connection string from
>   the above code

You can resolve a concrete registration by its name. It also true for the string class. I suppose the constructor of **IntegrationEntities** has Unity attribute with "*IntegrationEntityContent*" and it allows Unity container to inject the right connection string on Resolve.

> if the application is getting a new IntegrationEntities instance
>   every time it asks for one

With this configuration Unity will return the same instance per each container. If you container has children containers defined then they will have own instances of **IntegrationEntities**.